# Add parameter to command ADO.NET

Tags: sql, ado.net

I'm trying to select data from db with using this code:

```
 getForecastsCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP @Count * FROM Forecasts Order by [ForecastId] DESC";

   var countParam = getForecastsCommand.CreateParameter();
   countParam.ParameterName = "@Count";
   countParam.Value = count;
   countParam.DbType = DbType.Int32;
   getForecastsCommand.Parameters.Add(countParam);
```

But it isn't work:

```
Incorrect syntax near '@Count'.
```

Why isn't it work?

Comment: You should add a note on the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this `SELECT TOP (@Count) * FROM Forecasts Order by [ForecastId] DESC`

Please, note that @count is surrounded by parenthesis.

Comment: Also, please find some additional information about TOP clause here http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-use-a-variable-in-a-top-clause-in-sql-server.html

Answer (score 0):

That syntax looks like a Microsoft Access database. If it is, it does not support parameters for TOP. You will have to build the string.

```
@"SELECT TOP " + Count + " * FROM Forecasts Order by [ForecastId] DESC";
```